# Движение рук персонажа за камерой

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Всем привет. Недавно решил разработать свой FPS с 3D моделькой персонажа, т.е у нас не летающие в воздухе руки, а полноценная модель перса. Так вот движение рук за камерой я пытался сделать следующим образом: сделал отдельно руки и тело, затем руки сделал детьми камеры. При данном способе руки при повороте "выходили" за спину персонажа. На каком вообще принципе модели в FPS делаются? И как мне сделать нормальные движения рук?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чаще всего в FPS внешняя модель игрока не видима для самого игрока. Ему видима более детальная модель рук, оружия и частей туловища. Также отдельно прорабатывается их анимация.

В твоем варианте чаще всего делают два режима обзора камерой: свободный, когда руки пусты или нажата спец клавиша; и прицеливания, когда оружие перемещается вместе с камерой.

При свободном обзоре двигается обычно только голова, при прицеливании торс. Как только вращение при прицеливании превысит угол гибкости таза персонаж должен повернутся уже ногами. При очень резком повороте персонаж обычно поворачивается только за счет ног.

В любом случае самый простой способ это просто руки и отдельная механика поворота и наклона внешней модели.